# How do I get my XSLT to open HTML/PHP and accept an entire XML node rowset?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, parameters, xhtml

So far when I click on the XSLT embedded in my hyperlink, I get the page that I want. But, it is also where I need the help! I need my style_sheet to pass the entire row.node result as a parameter or array onclick so that I can embed and manipulate it via html for the resulting page call.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="property_resi.xsl"?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <ListingPrice>124000.00</ListingPrice>
        <ListingRid>59999991</ListingRid>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <StatusComments></StatusComments>
        <StatusDate>2007-07-24T00:00:00</StatusDate>
        <Stories>1.00</Stories>
        <StreetDirection>East</StreetDirection>
        <StreetName>San Sircettia</StreetName>
        <StreetNumber>410</StreetNumber>
        <StreetNumberModifier></StreetNumberModifier>
        <StreetPostDirection></StreetPostDirection>
        <StreetSuffix>St</StreetSuffix>
        <YearBuilt>1999</YearBuilt>
        <ZipCode>99999</ZipCode>
    </row>
    <row>
        <ListingPrice>98000.00</ListingPrice>
        <ListingRid>59999992</ListingRid>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <StatusComments></StatusComments>
        <StatusDate>2007-07-24T00:00:00</StatusDate>
        <Stories>1.00</Stories>
        <StreetDirection>South</StreetDirection>
        <StreetName>Tuscany</StreetName>
        <StreetNumber>560</StreetNumber>
        <StreetNumberModifier></StreetNumberModifier>
        <StreetPostDirection></StreetPostDirection>
        <StreetSuffix>Circle</StreetSuffix>
        <YearBuilt>2000</YearBuilt>
        <ZipCode>99999</ZipCode>
    </row>
    <row>
        <ListingPrice>805000.00</ListingPrice>
        <ListingRid>59999993</ListingRid>
        <Status>Active</Status>
        <StatusComments></StatusComments>
        <StatusDate>2007-07-24T00:00:00</StatusDate>
        <Stories>1.00</Stories>
        <StreetDirection>West</StreetDirection>
        <StreetName>Hill View Park</StreetName> 
        <StreetNumber>2205</StreetNumber>
        <StreetNumberModifier></StreetNumberModifier>
        <StreetPostDirection></StreetPostDirection>
        <StreetSuffix>Drive</StreetSuffix>
        <YearBuilt>1978</YearBuilt>
        <ZipCode>99999</ZipCode>
    </row>
</rows>






<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
          <body>
          <h2>Current Listings</h2>
               <table border="1">
                      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32"> </tr>
                      <xsl:for-each select="rows/row">
                  <xsl:sort select="City"/>
                  <xsl:sort select="ZipCode"/>
                       <tr> <td><a href="property_resi_xslt.html">
                                            <xsl:value-of-select=
                                                  "concat(StreetNumber, ' ',   
                                                   StreetDirection, ' ',    
                                                   StreetName, ' ', 
                                                   StreetSuffix, ' - ', City, 
                                                   ',', ZipCode, ' - ', '$', 
                                                   ListingPrice)"/> 
                                                   </a> 
                                                   </td> 
                   </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                 </table>
              </body>
    </html>



<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Lang" content="en" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript"/>
<meta name="author" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="Reply-to" content="@.com" />
<meta name="generator" content="PhpED 8.0" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="creation-date" content="06/09/2012" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="15 days" />
<title>Results page</title>
</head>
     <body>
          Insert & Manipulate`code here` My XML RESULTS HERE!!!!
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HC SVNT DRACONES. Can you format that document?

Comment: Also, as an alternative fix, for the parameter issue, I am also trying to embed .php in the anchor href, as follows, but no luck:        `<td> <a href="property_resi_xslt_test.php">`   `<xsl:value-of select="concat(StreetNumber, '`   `', StreetDirection, ' ', StreetName,`   `' ', StreetSuffix, ' - ', City,`   `',', ZipCode, ' - ',`   `'$', ListingPrice)"/> </a> </td>`  
               </tr>

Comment: So far I've got                                                  `<td> <a href="property_resi_xslt_test.php?ListingRid=$ListingRid;">`    `<xsl:value-of select="concat(StreetNumber,`  `' ', StreetDirection, ' ',`     `StreetName, ' ', StreetSuffix, ' - ', City, ',', ZipCode, ' - ',`    `'$', ListingPrice)"/> </a> </td>`              to open my php But it seems that it won;t accept more than one param, and the XSLT is not passing a value to the php, Not good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating HTML in the browser using XML and XSLT, but when the browser runs and displays the HTML it will no longer reference the original XML document. So, it is not really passing the "row.node result as a parameter". You will have to ensure that the data in the row set is somehow placed in your HTML document, where it can then be passed to your PHP page.

You give this example in your comment

```
 <a href="property_resi_xslt_test.php?ListingRid=$ListingRid;"><xsl:value-of select="concat(StreetNumber,' ', StreetDirection, ' ',StreetName, ' ', StreetSuffix, ' - ', City, ',', ZipCode, ' - ','$', ListingPrice)"/></a>
```

So, you are actually on the right lines already. I am assuming **$ListingRid** is a variable that you have set that contains the value of the **ListingRid** element. The syntax you actually want here is this

```
<a href="property_resi_xslt_test.php?ListingRid={$ListingRid}">
```

This is known as "Attribute Value Templates". The curly braces indicate it is an expression to be evaluated, rather than something to be output literally.

Assuming your current context was a **row** element, you wouldn't really need a variable here, you could just do this

```
<a href="property_resi_xslt_test.php?ListingRid={ListingRid}">
```

And, if you wanted to pass back more than one value, you could can use more than one AVT in the expression

```
<a href="property_resi_xslt_test.php?ListingRid={ListingRid}&amp;Status={Status}&amp;ZipCode={ZipCode}">
```

Of course, what you then do in your PHP page is an entirely different question. This is just showing you how to pass the values to the PHP in the first place.

Comment: I am able to make this work using a single parameter, but when I try multiple parameters, I get the following -              
**Warning: DOMDocument::load(): EntityRef: expecting ';' in C:/Users/vinlanders/Desktop/PHRETS/property_resi.xsl, line: 23 in C:\Users\vinlanders\Desktop\PHRETS\property_resi_xslt.php on line 13
Error! Unable to open C:/Users/vinlanders/Desktop/PHRETS/property_resi.xsl!**                   Is there a simple way to pass <row></row> as an array?  That would be the ideal solution...

Comment: Trying to pass row={row} in my php yields zilch.

Comment: My apologies. I've corrected the issue with passing multiple parameters. You have to encode the '&' in XSLT first, you see.

Comment: Doing `row={row}` would not work because {row} will return the text value of row, not the actual XML entity itself.